# Rewrite rule depending on optional parts of the parser rule in ANTLR3

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I'm trying to modify a rule depending on it's context with as few copy/paste as possible. I'll best begin with a pseudocode variant of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
module[boolean isParam]: 'module' id=identity?
        declaration+ 
        update+
        'endmodule' -> ^(MODULE ({if (isParam)} IS_PARAMETER {else} $id) declaration+ update+);
```

If `isParam` is set I want the module to not match the `identity` rule but create a `IS_PARAMETER` token in its place. I'm sure I can do this with two separate `module` rules but is there a cleaner way with less code duplication or without splitting the `module` rule into a number of smaller rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this works:

```
module[boolean isParam]: 'module' id=identity?
        declaration+ 
        update+
        'endmodule' -> {isParam}? ^(MODULE IS_PARAMETER declaration+ update+)
                    ->            ^(MODULE $id declaration+ update+);
```

Comment: Yes, however, since `identity` is optional, so should its label `$id` be in the rewrite rule.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, thanks. It seems `$id` does not need to be optional. Will it insert a `nil`node if it's not optional and the variable has not been set either?

Comment: @Lichtblitz, no, if it's optional in a parser rule and not optional in the rewrite rule, an exception is thrown when the node is not present (I believe when traversing the tree in a tree grammar, but perhaps during AST creation, I'm not 100% sure: try it to find out!).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the optional $id, I have to admit I didn't actually read the entire grammar ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested, this would work:

```
module[boolean isParam]
 : 'module' id=identity? declaration+ update+ 'endmodule' 
   -> {isParam}? ^(MODULE IS_PARAMETER declaration+ update+)
   ->            ^(MODULE $id? declaration+ update+)
 ;
```

*(note the optional `$id` however!)*

But by looking at your rule, I get the impression that whenever an `identity` is *not* present, you want to have a `IS_PARAMETER` node in your AST. If this is the case, you can handle this without parameters and predicates, which is IMO preferred:

```
module
 : 'module' ( identity declaration+ update+ 'endmodule' -> ^(MODULE identity declaration+ update+)
            | declaration+ update+ 'endmodule'          -> ^(MODULE IS_PARAMETER declaration+ update+)
            )
 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this was my personal fallback solution. Since I wanted to only allow a missing `identity` in certain contexts this solution would accept too much. Thanks anyways :-)

Comment: Ok, it was just a guess on my part. Good to know you found a solution.